# Fast way to get topN elements for each matrix column

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

This is the code snippet from `recommenderlab` package, that takes matrix with ratings and returns top 5 elements for each user -

```
reclist <- apply(ratings, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) 
  head(order(x, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=NA), 5))
```

For large matrix (>10K columns) it takes too long to run, is there any way to re-write it to make more efficient? Maybe by using dpyr, or data.table package)? Writing C++ code is not an option for me

Comment: How many rows do you have?

Comment: in my case, it's just 100. But as rows here represent items sold, that may be up to 1M. So this case may be interesting for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer with data.table and base R

```
# 10000 column dummy matrix
cols <- 10000
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*cols), ncol=cols)
```

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(mat)
# sort every column, return first 5 rows
dt1[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing=T)][1:5]
system.time(dt1[, lapply(.SD, sort, decreasing=T)][1:5])
```

result:

```
 user  system elapsed 
2.904   0.013   2.916
```

In plain old base, it's actually faster! (thanks for the comment Arun)

```
system.time(head(apply(mat, 2, sort, decreasing=T), 5))

 user  system elapsed 
0.473   0.002   0.475
```

However, both are faster than the code sample above, according to system.time()

```
system.time(
apply(mat, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) {
  head(order(x, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=NA), 5)
}))

user  system elapsed 
3.063   0.031   3.094
```

Comment: What exactly is the advantage of using `data.table` here?

Comment: Yeah, good point. I just did that since OP mentioned it, but when I compare head to head, it's faster to just operate on the matrix directly.

Comment: No worries. `apply + sort` seems great! Maybe try `sort.int` with `partial=5L` as well... The bottleneck seems to be `sorting/ordering` though. `data.table`'s internal radix order `forderv` (not exported yet) may be of use, especially if there are also a lot of rows!